# GCP Cloud scheduler unauthorized to call cloud function that requires authentication: The request was not authenticated

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless, google-cloud-scheduler

I'm getting the following error when trying to call a cloud function from cloud scheduler:

```
The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header.
```

I basically did the following steps:

1. Create cloud function:

```bash
gcloud functions deploy test-function \
--runtime=python310 \
--trigger-http \
--entry-point=start_script \
--region=europe-west3 \
--max-instances=1 \
--timeout=350s \
--memory=1GiB \
--service-account=973117053722-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
--ingress-settings=all \
--no-allow-unauthenticated \
--gen2 \
--source=./path/to/dir
```

2. Deploy cloud scheduler:

```bash
gcloud scheduler jobs create http test-scheduler \
--schedule="0 4 * * *" \
--http-method=POST \
--uri="https://europe-west3-propane-nomad-396712.cloudfunctions.net/test-function" \
--headers="Content-Type=application/json" \
--attempt-deadline=1800s \
--location='europe-west3' \
--oidc-service-account-email=cloud-scheduler@propane-nomad-396712.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

3. Get the list of current services:

```bash
gcloud run services list --platform=managed
```

4. Used the address listed from the previous step to grant roles/run.invoker to this cloud function:

```bash
gcloud run services add-iam-policy-binding test-function \
    --member="serviceAccount:service-973117053722@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role="roles/run.invoker"
```

Note:

- I used the default compute service account for my cloud function. I created my own service account for cloud scheduler which has the permission to invoke cloud functions (http and pub/sub).
- I want the cloud function to require authentication.
- I initally did step 1 and 2 and this didn't work so I added step 3 and 4 based on the warning that is displayed in cloud functions ("Warning: You must assign the Invoker role (roles/run.invoker) through Cloud Run for 2nd gen functions if you want to allow the function to receive requests from additional principals or other given authorities in IAM.")

**Update:**
As suggested after step 2 I ran the following command:

```bash
gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding test-function \
    --member="serviceAccount:cloud-scheduler@propane-nomad-396712.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role="roles/cloudfunctions.invoker" \
    --region='europe-west3'
```

This does not work for gen2 cloud functions. However gcloud asked if I want to execute the correct command directly:

```bash
This does not grant the member permission to invoke 2nd gen function [test-function]. Instead, the role [roles/run.invoker] must be granted on the underlying Cloud Run service. This can be done by running the `gcloud functions add-invoker-policy-binding` command.

Would you like to run this command and additionally grant 
[serviceAccount:cloud-scheduler@propane-nomad-396712.iam.gserviceaccount.com] 
permission to invoke function [test-function] (Y/n)?
```

After confirming it worked. Now I wonder what the command actually is that gcloud runs under the hood? I redeployed the cloud-function/cloud-scheduler and tried the following command:

```bash
gcloud functions add-invoker-policy-binding test-function \
    --member="serviceAccount:cloud-scheduler@propane-nomad-396712.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --region='europe-west3'
```

The command ran successfully but it did not work when I triggered the cloud scheduler. I still got the same error as before.

Comment: You ran the command `gcloud run services add-iam-policy-binding ...` but Cloud Scheduler is calling Cloud Functions. To authorize Scheduler to call Functions, use `gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding ...`.

Comment: Note: Scheduler will use this identity to call Functions `cloud-scheduler@propane-nomad-396712.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.

Comment: @JohnHanley Your suggestion does not work for gen2 cloud functions but it did point me in the right direction with the gcloud auto correction. However I can't figure out what command gcloud actually ran to make it work.

Comment: Did you specify the `--gen2` command flag? Document [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/add-iam-policy-binding#--gen2).

Comment: No but it says: ```shell
defaults to looking up the given function and using its generation
```
As I deployed a gen2 function it should use that automatically

Comment: Lots of `ifs` for that flag. I always specify `--gen2`.

Comment: After some testing turns out that my last stated command is actually working fine. However for some reason it takes 5-10 minutes until the permissions are actually granted.

Comment: If you use Cloud Functions 2nd gen, which is backed on Cloud Run, you must use the ` --oidc-token-audience=` equals to the Cloud Functions base URL

Comment: Yeah I tried with and without this flag. So if you leave out this flag it uses the uri url as default anyway. But even if you add this flag it does not change the fact that it takes a few minutes for the permissions to take affect for some reason. But I can live with that. Thank you for the guidance